# how to align buttons in css/html in one line horizontally?

Tags: html, css, button

I am having difficulty aligning SNS buttons using CSS on this page giantmango.com/news.  I am using the exact css and html, but I cannot align giantmango.com/news SNS buttons like the giantmango.com ones.

Comment: its because div.mixi a img is just much larger then the rest (15px + 02.em + 8px + height)

Comment: try adding `border: 0pt none; padding: 0pt; margin: 0pt;` to `div.mixi a img`

Comment: @Sotiris SNS = Social Network

Comment: @Hannes how is giantmango.com buttons different from giantmango.com/news buttons?

Comment: @tokyowp  the button that works doesn't have all the additional padding and margin stuff that the failing one has

Comment: @Hannes I am actually using the same div class for both giantmango.com and giantmango.com/news

Comment: @tokyowp :D just use firebug its extreeemly obvious ^^ /news runs under wordprss i assume so here now applys the `.post img` entry from the `http://giantmango.com/wp-content/themes/modernist/style.css` file that adds more padding & margin to the image and makes it fail :D so ether move the SNS out of div.post or edit the style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you talk about social netoworks buttons, then you can make the first to be upper adding `margin-top: -8px;` for `#content .mixi` in style.css

Comment: problem with this is it makes the giantmango.com button go up

Comment: just added more classes.  heavier css file, but will have to do for now

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Set the width of the UL element to something that would fit all LI elements (e.g. if each of the LI element is 20px wide and there are 5 elements, the UL element should be at least 100px.)  You should also consider the padding and margin of each of the UL element and add that to the total width of the UL element.
- Set the style of the LI element to: `li { float: right; }`